# How to find files in the directory “/path/to/directory/” which contains information "SomeText" if they are in archives .gz?

Tags: shell, find, gzip

I am using RHEL. How can I find files in the directory `/path/to/directory/`  which contain  the string `SomeText`  if those files are .gz archives?

Comment: Are they simple files compressed with `gzip` or are they compressed `tar.gz` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zgrep` just like you would use `grep`:

```
zgrep SomeText /path/to/directory/*
```

Or, to make it recursive (if you have [Zutils](https://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html)), including hidden files:

```
zgrep -R SomeText /path/to/directory/
```

Or, to make it recursive (without Zutils):

```
find /path/to/directory/ -type -f -exec zgrep SomeText {} +
```